# What's a consistent set of Intel HPL options?

Tags: mpi, benchmarking, intel, linpack

I'm trying to run the intel version of the HPL benchmark [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-linux-developer-guide/top/intel-math-kernel-library-benchmarks/intel-distribution-for-linpack-benchmark/running-the-intel-distribution-for-linpack-benchmark.html) and I'm a bit confused by the options.

What I want to do (for now) is a single-node run. The node has 2x Xeon Platinum 8276 processors, so 56 cores total. So my PxQ should be 56.

However the intel docs say:

- MPI_PROC_NUM should be equal to PxQ (i.e 56) - this gets passed to `mpirun -np`
- MPI_PER_NODE should be equal to the number of sockets in the system (i.e. 2) - this gets passed to `mpirun -perhost`

To me those don't seem consistent? And how does using OMP_NUM_THREADS fit into this?

Comment: It seems the doc suggests you run a hybrid MPI+OpenMP HPL. That means `OMP_NUM_THREADS=28` and `PxQ=2`.

Comment: Thank you. I was misled by expectations from the open-source HPL. In fact it turns out that using MKL it automatically picks the number of threads to add, using TBB rather than openmp, hence OMP_NUM_THREADs does nothing. Not obvious IMHO so might help someone!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just doing a single node run there is a different binary for that - you wouldn't use MPI. For Intel's MKL, you would download the library [here](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/793598/l_onemklbench_p_2024.0.0_49515.tgz)

Intel has pre-built binaries that are optimized for their various processors. Ex for Xeon it is:

```bash
cd /home/grant/Downloads/benchmarks_2024.0/linux/share/mkl/benchmarks/linpack
./runme_xeon64
```